# Chat Application using SignalR and Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, signalr

I am developing a chat application.I use SignalR and Ionic for this.And I get an error on the Ionic side.

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalR.Startup))]

   namespace SignalR
{
   public class Startup
     {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
          {

        app.MapSignalR();
        }
     }
  }
```

**ChatHub.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

  namespace SignalR
 {
       public class ChatHub : Hub
     {


      public void Send(string username,string message)

       {
        Clients.All.sendMessage(username,message);

       }
      }
    }
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope) {


$scope.name = 'Onur'; // holds the user's name
$scope.message = ''; // holds the new message
$scope.messages = []; // collection of messages coming from server
$scope.chatHub = null; // holds the reference to hub

$scope.chatHub = $.connection.chatHub; // initializes hub
$.connection.hub.start(); // starts hub

// register a client method on hub to be invoked by the server
$scope.chatHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
    var newMessage = name + ' says: ' + message;

    // push the newly coming message to the collection of messages
    $scope.messages.push(newMessage);
    $scope.$apply();
};

$scope.newMessage = function () {
    // sends a new message to the server
    $scope.chatHub.server.sendMessage($scope.name, $scope.message);

    $scope.message = '';
};

 })
```

Faield to load resource
  hubs(0,0)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'chatHub' of undefined

I'm getting errors.Where am I doing wrong.Help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the hub after registering client methods. It should work.